# Value not being entered into the MySQL database correctly

Tags: php, mysql

The value for a field (phone number) isn't being correctly entered into the database. That is, the value seems to change once it's entered.

The phone number has a max limit of 11 characters. In the HTML form, I set the 4 initial defaults characters to 1876 - Jamaica's area code.

```
<tr>
                <td>Phone:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="11" value="1876" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/></td>
              </tr>
```

Then, on the php side:

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

All other values in the field are being entered correctly.

Where did I go wrong?

UPDATE:

In the MySQL table, the column data type is an int.

It's inserted using this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, phone) 
      VALUES ('$id','$first_name','$last_name','$encrypted_dob','$email','$phone')";
```

For example, I tried entering, say, 3025009 and it's storing some random value like 2147483647.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is an example of a value you enter, and what gets stored in the database? What type is the MySQL column?

Comment: Do you have an example of how the phone number isn't being entered correctly? You might need to show some more PHP code.

Comment: Could you please tell what actually gets inserted for phone?

Comment: You used a table for layout, you used inline JavaScript, you used XHTML without following the HTML Compatibility Guidelines, you didn't use `<label>` … and you didn't provide any of the PHP that does anything with the data … and you were incredibly vague about what is actually happening when you run that code.

Comment: OP has being updated.

@Quentin: Everything else is being entered correctly. I provided all the necessary that has anything to do with the datafield 'phone'.

In fact, before I bothered to add the default area code value (1876), it was being inserted just fine.

Comment: I hope you are coding against SQL injection.

Comment: @liquorvicar Yes sir, all values were santitized before being inserted :)

Comment: Just checking ;-) btw you might want to investigate PDO as it can handle db escaping for you.

Comment: Alright sure, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem of datatype signed int which is able to store maximum 2147483647 value in it if you try to store larger value then limit then it will store datatype's maximum limit which is 2147483647.
so please use appropriate datatype to store integer value.
some references are follows which may fulfill your requirement.

```
datatype                    largest value

bigint unsigned             18446744073709551615
bigint signed               9223372036854775807
int unsigned                4294967295
```

Answer (score 2):

its problem of integer size you have to change data type size "int" to "bigint"  then you can get correct value try this it works