# Mysql stores the number differently

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store a phone number in mysql database. But it stores a different value.

```
<form align="center" method="post" action="sendingdata.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="phone">Phone Number </label></br>
            <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="90000 12345"/>


            <input class="submit" type="submit" />
```

The following is the sendingdata.php

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$q = sprintf("insert into posts(title,price,description,imagepath,name,phone) values('%s',%d,'%s','%s','%s','%d')", mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title), mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $price), mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $description), mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $imageName),mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username),mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $phone));

if (mysqli_query($conn, $q)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo "success";
}
```

The value I tried to input is 90000 00000. But the value stored in database is 2147483647

ps: The data type in mysql is BIG INT

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the MySQL database?

Comment: You try to store data in Decimal format, check your field type.

Comment: the data type in mysql is BIG INT @mcklayin

Comment: @gates  you can store it in TEXT format.

Comment: A phone number is not a number, store it text or varchar

Comment: Data type is obviously not `bigint`. Also, what @cske said - store the phone number in textual format.

Comment: Are you at all suspicious that **2^31-1** = **2147483647** ?

Answer (score 3):

That is the [maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) `INT` size.  Consider using a either `BIGINT` or a `VARCHAR` [column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html), or a `CHAR` column with a fixed width.

`INT`'s maximum size is "2147483647" is signed and "4294967295" unsigned.  Whereas a `CHAR` with a fixed length can be any number that is X digits/characters long.  If you use a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` column, be sure to validate your input first, as it will allow more than numbers in the value.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your data type to VARCHAR (or CHARACTER (n)) instead of BIG INT. Phone number is basically an information, no need to calculate with it, so it is better when you store in string type data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your datatype of your phone field is int so it is not able to store 90000 00000 try by changing it to bigint.

Comment: Previously , Mysql filed type was int. Still no use

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953743/value-not-being-entered-into-the-mysql-database-correctly/9954026#9954026